# Update PHP variable in switch statement (simple)

Tags: php, variables, scope, switch-statement

In PHP, I have a value outside of a switch called $chickens, equal to 1. After going through a switch statement, I want the value to change to b.

```
//original value of var
$chickens = 1;

switch ($chickens) {
  case "0":
    $chickens === "a";
    break;
  case "1":
    $chickens === "b";
    break;
  case "2":
    $chickens === "c";
    break;
  case "3":
    $chickens === "b";
    break;
}

//want this to be "b" defined in switch
echo $chickens;
```

For some reason the value does not update :(. Any Ideas

Comment: @Trudbert It has to be a copying error or the code wouldn't run at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong operator. `=` is the assignment operator. `===` is a comparison operator:

```
//original value of var
$chickens = 1;

switch ($chickens) {
  case "0":
    $chickens = "a";
    break;
  case "1":
    $chickens = "b";
    break;
  case "2":
    $chickens = "c";
    break;
case "3":
    $chickens = "d";
    break;
}

//want this to be "b" defined in switch
echo $chickens;
```

Comment: Wow, I think this is the first time I've seen the error in this direction. It's almost always using `=` when `==` was needed.

Comment: Wow thanks, dumb mistake, but it solved the problem. Appreciate the extremely speedy response!